# How to rewrite URLs for Android WebView (and/or Crosswalk) resource requests?

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk-runtime

I'd like to rewrite the URL used for resource requests coming from an Android WebView.  The hook that I see for doing things like that is to override shouldInterceptRequest on the WebView's WebViewClient.  However, that method only provides a String url and does not provide access to the request details (headers, etc).  As a result, it's impossible to know if a call is a GET or POST / an Ajax call / etc, etc.

Is there some other Android WebView hook that provides you with the chance to rewrite a resource URL while preserving the rest of the request?

On IOS it looks like you can provide a custom implementation of NSURLCache that could perform the rewriting.  Is there anything similar on Android?

(Also, I'm actually using the Crosswalk browser rather than the stock webview - which is very similar in API to the standard Android WebView.  I'd be interested in solutions for either crosswalk or the Android WebView.)

Comment: I *hope* that's not possible.

Comment: @user3249477 - It sounds like you're raising a privacy concern.  If you are interacting with a webview inside a third-party app, you have very little privacy protection in the first place - this feature certainly doesn't make it worse.  In my use case, the url rewriting is for purposes that benefit the user. :)

Comment: Just wondering, did you find a solution? I am looking into the same problem :)